# iOS: How is Spotify kept alive in background when used as a remote?

Tags: ios, spotify

From what I recall your app gets killed when executing in the background unless you actually play some audible sound through an audio session, but Spotify can somehow stay alive while being used as a remote control app even though it's not visible, doesn't play audio, doesn't track location, etc. It **stays reactive to volume changes and server communication** while being backgrounded. How?

Spotify implements their own network based cross-platform remote control of their apps.

For some reason I cannot find much [info on background modes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW22) to shed light on what they could be doing. I can't find a documented use case that includes remote control.

For those who doubt that Spotify vends its own remote control solution I disabled Bluetooth and WiFi and kept using it as if nothing had happened. This is not about AirPlay, Bluetooth, etc.

*iOS 13*

Comment: You can play an audio file with nothing but silence, it's possible that Spotify does this and responds to control center events by sending them through a websocket or something.

Comment: @donnywals Really? I was under the impression that that wouldn't work and that iOS actively monitored for that. I seem to remember getting suspended when trying to do that with a speech synthesizer in earlier versions. Maybe I'm wrong. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think it needs to do anything -- the media controller remembers the last app that played media as long as it isn't killed. This works for pretty much any media app (podcast players, etc).

Comment: @Andreas you are right -- it was a trick that used to work, but Apple explicitly forbids it now.  I don't think they actively monitor it, but I bet they would certainly ding Spotify if they did it.

Comment: @LouFranco Thanks. Maybe I forgot to mention though: it's actively playing according to the system's media controls so it's not just remembered as the last audio source but actually treated as running in the background.

Comment: Ah, I wasn't aware that they forbid tricks like that now. In that case I'm not sure what they do..

Comment: Why exactly do you think it is actively playing or running in the background.  I am using a podcast player right now -- it is backgrounded and not playing.  The system media player  knows what app last sent the audio play request and it shows details of the podcast.  This is true for every media playing app on my device.

Comment: I would make a simple media player and try it.  Post what the exact difference between Spotify and your app are with screenshots

Comment: @LouFranco Because it reacts to volume changes and forwards them over the network. It updates media info when the song changes. Etc. It necessarily has to run at least *some* code in the background.

Comment: I don't understand what you are doing exactly.  How do you know iOS isn't sending volume over the network.  Are you talking about AirPlay?  iOS knows what's going on -- it could make all the AirPlay calls.

Comment: Spotify has its own remote implementation that works over internet. It's their own. Not AirPlay, not Bluetooth, and not an audio cable from my phone :)

Comment: It's also good to mention that the progress bar in the control center still moves forward, representing the playback progress on the other device. Which like @Andreas said can be any device. Doesn't even have to be on the same WiFi AFAIK

Comment: Interesting -- I suspect that having the open audio session (and the audio background mode) gives you some callbacks even if audio is currently paused. I would try it (or if you have, show us your volume observing code)

Comment: I bet you just get updates if you have a running audio session -- have you tried it?

Comment: @donnywals Actually, I deliberately did not mention the progress bar since — just like in game engines — Apple compensates for the fact that they're not going to ask the source app for timeline updates every single second. The timeline in iOS is extrapolating the last known playback state by incrementing the progress by itself in a timely manner without hiccups. It's not possible to get such smooth incremental updates in playback position without such a strategy. You can see it self-correcting when you use streaming apps on bad networks that unexpectedly stop. Just like games with high latency

Comment: @Andreas Right, but if you forward the playhead on the target device it also updates the playhead on the iPhone which, in my opinion, is an important detail in terms of the server-side being able to push updates to the device.

Comment: @donnywals I've emphasized it and updated the question.

Comment: I have given the answer on this thread before.. it was not accepted after many explanations. The code is now removed as it will never satisfy you. I hope you find what you are looking for. I am very sorry I cannot be of more help. I am upvoting your question in hopes someone else comes along and gives you better code than I gave + a running server + videos of it working https://i.imgur.com/aHnqxlq.mp4 (with media playing) https://i.imgur.com/sEvN2XA.mp4 (without media playing). I honestly hope you get the answer so I can look at it and see what I missed. I have favourited this question.

Comment: @Brandon Well, we can't help if you decide to expend all your time and effort by writing an answer, so that when anyone tries to clarify something by asking a followup question you feel justified to use your expended effort as an excuse to give them an irritable reply. It was not hard to predict that you would eventually delete your answer based on how you reacted to the other commenters, so don't worry, I saved a copy. But please stop acting as though I asked you to code my app for you, let alone asked for any code whatsoever. I might have believed your sincerity, had you left your answer up.

Comment: The other comments **without** even verifying it or checking if it works, immediately downvoted it because they assumed it wasn't what you asked for. I have said many times, RUN the code, read the explanation and you will understand why it works ("background entitlements + remove player layer + set session active") + two videos + images + a python server written just for the answer + links to apple docs explaining it. I am not obligated to satisfy whether or not you "believe" it will work. You ask for an answer, you got a "working" answer, but it isn't enough because you don't "think" it works

Comment: There is no point wasting space or more time on it from my point of view. Answers are FREE. If someone gives you the code and an explanation and documentation and some videos of it, TRY IT OUT.. Not deny that it works. In that case, it's just best to remove it then. Anyone would be irritated having to post 2 videos, write the server, the answer, accept the downvotes, and explain it and STILL get told: "I'm sorry, I can't accept this answer". I am not here for that. Either accept it or don't (it is your choice). If I know you won't, I delete it as it serves no purpose.

Comment: @Brandon I'm sorry about your experience with the downvoting. It is of course not fun after writing an extensive answer. I don't vote frivolously. I never denied that your code worked. I concluded that the necessary explanation was missing of what kept it from being suspended in the way I described in my question, which you justify by having provided lots of code insead. Had you simply written "an active audio session and background audio capabilities are -- contrary to your understanding -- enough to keep an app from being suspended by iOS" then you would already have been ahead...

Comment: Which part of this made no sense: `You now need some notifications for when the application goes in the background. It WILL NOT WORK without this` + Apple Docs +  `I have explained that this enables background mode and background controls but it seems..` + `My code literally does everything being asked for (enabling backgrounding)` + `Don't forget to set the background mode` +  `My point is, once you have background mode working, you can do whatever you want. Make requests, open sockets/streams, etc.. – Brandon 4 hours ago ` + working code + 2 videos..

Comment: @Brandon You are free to undelete your answer if you are sincere about wanting to clarify it. The sentence you quoted that touches the subject of apps being suspended in the background on iOS is "once you have background mode working, you can do whatever you want" which of course conflicts with what I described in the question, regarding criteria for apps to get suspended. Notwithstanding the fact that that sentence wasn't part of the answer, that would have been a good place to point out that apps don't get suspended after having not played audio for a while, contrary to my understanding.